# "Hello World" programme for Bottle.py

Tags: python, bottle

I just tried the Quickstart: "Hello, World!" tutorial of bottle.py (http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#quickstart-hello-world)

But i am getting an error of this kind:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bottle import route, run
  File "/home/sid/bottle.py", line 3, in <module>
    @route('/hello/<name>')
NameError: name 'route' is not defined
```

Comment: you need to install bottle module.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the error is on that exactly line: `from bottle import route, run`.

Comment: Check the bottle package is installed correctly: have you run - 

 `sudo pip install bottle` ?

Comment: Do you have a file named `bottle.py` by any chance? Yeah, you have it. Rename it.

Comment: Change your filename to something else.

Comment: I did actually name the previous attempt bottle.py but i realized it and started off with first.py but didn't delete 'bottle.py' and .pyc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name your own file `bottle.py` because it'll shadow the actual `bottle` library.